# Python 3.3 can't seem to find the decoder module in pocketsphinx library

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py, cmusphinx

I am getting the error **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Decoder'.**
I am using the following code. Because there was no setup.py file included I moved the dlls and libraries into their respective folders in the python33 directory manually.  (Library files in lib and dlls in DLLs). I am able to import the pocketsphinx and sphinxbase modules without error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pocketsphinx 
import sphinxbase 



lmd="C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\model\lm\HUB4_trigram_lm\language_model.arpaformat"
hmd="C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\model\hmm\en_US"
dictd="C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\model\lm\HUB4_trigram_lm\language_model.vocabulary"

fh = open('test1.wav', 'rb')
fh.seek(44)
decoder = pocketsphinx.Decoder(hmmd,lmd, dictp)
nsamp = Decoder.decode_raw(fh)

hyp, uttid, score = decoder.get_hyp()
print('Got result'+ hyp+'score'+score)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nsamp = Decoder.decode_raw(fh)

This part must be `decoder.decode_raw(fh)`. You are trying to look for Decoder in default module instead of method in an object.